# How to change the Control+Space autocomplete shortcut keys in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete

When I am in an Android xml file (an activity menu, for example) and type

```
android:
```

then autocomplete pops up and I can select an option. However, if I have something like

```
android:showAsAction=""
```

with my cursor inside the quotes, then I don't get an autocomplete for  options inside the quotes. I've heard that pressing Control+Space should do that but on my computer Control+Space is used to switch the language input method. Is there a way in Eclipse to change this shortcut key?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To change your keyboard shortcuts go to:

1. Window
2. Preferences
3. General
4. Keys

From there you can filter the list to find "**content assist**" and assign the value you'd like.

[image: Example]

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! That was just what I was looking for. The picture helped, too.